# wildcard domain redirect in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have already setup my DNS to point all sub domains to @, and I can tell that that is working because I am now getting an appengine error that the URL was not found on the server.

How can I setup my app.yaml file to catch and point all subdomains of my custom domain to the same static file?
Thanks!

**Example:**

http://learnnow.us
(works)

http://something.learnnow.us
(does not)

```
DNS Entry

name  |  type   |   data
*     |  CNAME  |   @


app.yaml

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index\.html

- url: *
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index\.html
```

Comment: In app.yaml you specify handlers for your App. Subdomain wildcard configuration is explained at[1]. Static file handlers are explained at [2]. Can you please add more details on your use case: What this static file is going to be? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#more_about_wildcard_subdomain_mapping
  [2]: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a Google Apps account, to map all sub-domains to your app you need to add your App in the App Engine Apps section of the Admin console for learnnow.us. Then you add a mapping *.learnnow.us and create a CNAME record for * pointing to ghs.googlehosted.com.
 It may also be possible to do it via Developers Console -> Your_App -> Compute -> App Engine -> Settings -> Custom Domains (didn't test it though).

Comment: I switched the cname to ghs.googlehosted.com... but same error.
(Example, if you go to someting.learnnow.us, you will see the appengine 404 error, instead of the default browser 404 error.  If you go to b.site4u2.com you will get the default browser error.)
I believe it is a configuration of the app.yaml that has an error...

Comment: But have you added a mapping *.g.learnnow.us for your app in the Google Apps Admin console?

Answer (score 0):

Subdomain mapping is done on a DNS level. Configure this through the DNS service provider you have registered with. Map all subdomains to your main domain.

Route mapping is done in app.yaml. Once a request reaches your app, a route configuration in app.yaml with `url: /.*` will map all routes to that handler.

Given that your confusion about DNS mapping vs app.yaml route configuration should be cleared up, please accept this answer as valid. If you are experiencing other issues doing more complex things, as it seems from your comments, create a new question. Edits to your question should only contain more relevant info to the original question and comments should not introduce new questions.